django deploywment with daphne
I want to up my django server with run this command for in daphne:
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 9001 core.asgi:application

And this error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 17, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/./core/asgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    from stream.routing import ws_urlpatterns
  File "/app/./stream/routing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .consumers import OccurrenceConsumer
  File "/app/./stream/consumers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import  Occurrence 
  File "/app/./stream/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Asset(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.


as observed server did not run.
It seems that a model or app not recognize. this is my INSTALLED_APPS:
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    # my apps:
    "accounts",
    "api",
    "sms",
    "ticket",
    "base",
    "finances",
    "stream",
    "assistant",

    # add apps:
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "django_extensions",
    "corsheaders", 
    "channels",
    "daphne",
    "drf_yasg", 
    "solo",

    # base apps:
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    ]

who can help me?!
after this i want to deploy my server with nginx. i run server with my http and ws protocols.

Try moving "daphne" to the top of your INSTALLED APPS and see if that helps the issue.
